How to get a Tag value in a .heex file and assign to a variable using Phoenix and Elixir
I have the following snippet code:
 <div class="container mx-auto p-4">
    <div class="mb-4">

      <!-- Limite de banners -->
      <label for="limit" class="text-gray-700 ml-4">Limite de banners</label>
      <select id="limit" name="limit" class="ml-2 p-2 border rounded appearance-none pr-8">
        <option value="5" selected>5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
      </select>
      
      <!-- Botão de busca -->
      <button id="search" class="ml-2 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
        Buscar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

I want to assign the option tag value to my var called @limit and pass it into the url path when I click on the button with id=search.
I don't have any idea how to do this. I found almost nothing on the internet about my problem. I'm not using LiveView on my Phoenix project.

Some options are:

Wrap your code in a <form> tag without the action attribute but with method GET and make the button a submit button.
Put some javascript in a <script> tag to handle a value change on the radios, deconstruct the current url and add/update the limit param, reload the page with the updated url.

If all you want is to update/reload the page with a new limit query param, I would suggest to try #1 first as it is the most simple solution.

Thank you for your help. I used JavaScript , through the
The added value of LiveView lies in the fact that it provides a perfect tool to design single page application. You can use assigns to store dynamic value that will condition the content of your page:
@available_limits ["5", "10", "20"]

@impl true
def update_many(assigns_and_socket) do
    Enum.map(assigns_and_socket, fn
        {assigns, socket} ->
            socket
            |> assign(current_limit: nil)
    end)
end

@impl true
def render(assigns) do
    ~H """
        <div class="container mx-auto p-4">
            <div class="mb-4">
              <%= if is_nil(@current_limit) do %>
                  <form id="id-of-the-form-for-tests" phx-submit="search" phx-target={@myself}>
                      <label for="limit" class="text-gray-700 ml-4">Limite de banners</label>
                      <select id="limit" name="limit" class="ml-2 p-2 border rounded appearance-none pr-8">
                        <%= for limit <- available_limits() do %>
                           <option value={limit} selected={@current_limit == limit}><%= limit %></option>
                        <% end %>
                      </select>
  
                      <button id="search" type="submit" class="ml-2 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                        Buscar
                      </button>
                    </form>
              <% else %>
                 <!-- The result -->
              <% end %>
           </div>
       </div>
    """
end

@impl true
def handle_event("search", %{"limit" => limit}, socket) do
    ...
    {:noreply, socket |> assigns(:current_limit, limit)}
end

defp available_limits(), do: @available_limits

Note: In this example this is a LiveComponent, if in your case you are in a LiveView don't use update_many/1 but mount/3 and put the render/1 content into your .heex template.
